# React can't update displayed info of country when API returns weather data

Tags: reactjs, render

This is my code outside of the renders. I am trying to get countries data such as name, flag, languages, area. that's coming up correctly. what I also want to do is this: when response from hitting weather API (2nd API) comes, I want to set state of weatherDetails, let the program know the data has arrived, and then rerender it to show the weatherDetails ALONGSIDE the other country data which is already being displayed.

I type A, Az, and everything is alright. The problem happens when I write Aze, which gives back only 1 country, Azerbaijan, rendering infinite times. This is the code for logic outside of rerendering/return statements

```
    const [countryFilter, setCountryFilter] = useState('')
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([])
  const [showCountry, setShowCountry] = useState('')
  const [showWeather, setShowWeather] = useState(false)
  const [weatherDetails, setWeatherDetails] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  const handleCountryChange = (event) => {
    setCountryFilter(event.target.value)
    console.log(event.target.value)
    setShowWeather(false)
  }

  const searchCountries = () => {
    axios.get(`https://studies.cs.helsinki.fi/restcountries/api/all`)
      .then(response => {
        const FilteredCountries = response.data
        .filter(country => 
          country.name.common.toLowerCase().includes(countryFilter.toLowerCase()) || 
          country.name.official.toLowerCase().includes(countryFilter.toLowerCase())  
        )

        // console.log('response of searchCOuntries', FilteredCountries)

        setCountries(FilteredCountries)

      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('error:', error)
      })
  }

  const getWeather = () => {
    console.log('gonna try to get weather')
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://weatherapi-com.p.rapidapi.com/current.json',
      params: {q: countryFilter},
      headers: {
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': '62b1eab6ddmsh901e2fb3d7df102p1a8884jsn1c82e8127c80',
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'weatherapi-com.p.rapidapi.com'
      }
    }

    setLoading(true)
    console.log('in the try block')
    const request = axios.request(options)
    request
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
        setWeatherDetails(response.data.current)
        setLoading(false)

      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
    
  }
  useEffect(searchCountries, [ countryFilter ])

  useEffect( () => {
    if(showWeather) {
      getWeather()
    }
  }, [])
```

this is problematic block: if i remove if(weatherDetails && loading === false) which tells us that loading has finished and weatherDetails are ready for displaying, infinite rerenders happen. If I don't, weatherDetails.condition.text comes up as undefined.

```
else if (countries.length === 1) {

    console.log('reached 1 country block, this is problematic block: if i remove if(weatherDetails &&...), infinite rerenders.if i dont, .text undefined.')

    const ourCountry = countries[0]
    setShowWeather(true)

    if(weatherDetails && loading === false) {
      return (
        <>
          <span>find countries</span>
          <input type="text" value={countryFilter} onChange={handleCountryChange}/>
          
          <h1>{ourCountry.name.common}</h1>
          // ... other non-weather details...

          <h2>Weather in Helsinki</h2>
          <p>weather right now is {weatherDetails.condition.text}</p>
          <p>temperature {weatherDetails.temp_c} Celsius</p>
          <p>wind {weatherDetails.wind_kph} kph/s</p>
  
        </>
      )
    
    }
  }
```

[image: How app looks like before I type "Aze", currently have typed "Az" and am getting 3 countries. Typing "Aze" will cause error, screen will go blank, and errors defined above will come in console]